# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable (for print statement)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples, google-colaboratory

```
import numpy as np
a=np.load('ampli/array.npy')
print(a)
```

Im trying to print an npy array like this from colab. I've used this exact syntax to print other arrays and it has worked but this isnt working suddenly. I tried opening a new notebook and uploaded the npy file there and it printed it out without any issue. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that it is your `print` that is not callable.

Where the line `print(a)` fails, replace by `print("1")` and make sure it fails also.

Then find where the `print` built-in method is being assigned to some tuple.